# Install and integrate Apache OpenNLP in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, gradle, chatbot, opennlp

I am developing a ChatBot android application for which I wanted to use Apache OpenNLP library. I have followed this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/opennlp/opennlp_environment.htm) to download and use OpenNLP. After downloading the zip files, I was told to add 2 jar files to Android Studio as libraries which I have done. Then I have added the compile options to the build.gradle file of the modules directory. When I tried running the app, I got a Gradle Build error as following

```
> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add 
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
to that submodule's build.gradle file.
```

Then I have added the following lines to my gradle file

```
compileOptions{
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

After doing this, when I try to run the code. I get this failed gradle sync

```
 Error:Jack is required to support java 8 language features. Either enable Jack or remove sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.
Error:Jack is required to support java 8 language features. Either enable Jack or remove sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.
```

Then I add the following to my gradle file inside the defaultConfig block

```
jackOptions{
            enabled true
        }
```

After this when I try to run my app, I get the maximum number of errors

```
Error:Lambda coming from jar file need their interfaces on the classpath to be compiled, unknown interfaces are java.io.FileFilter
Error:Lambda coming from jar file need their interfaces on the classpath to be compiled, unknown interfaces are java.io.FileFilter
Error:Lambda coming from jar file need their interfaces on the classpath to be compiled, unknown interfaces are java.io.FileFilter
Error:Default method void updateAdaptiveData(java.lang.String[] tokens, java.lang.String[] outcomes) not supported in Android API level less than 24
Error:Default method void clearAdaptiveData() not supported in Android API level less than 24
Error:Default method void reset() not supported in Android API level less than 24
Error:Default method void close() not supported in Android API level less than 24
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithPreJackPackagedLibrariesForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.core.JackToolchain$ToolchainException: Jack compilation exception
```

Could anyone please tell me what to do? I would like to be able to use OpenNLP methods in my application. I have tried cleaning and rebuilding but in vain.

Answer (score 3):

Below gradle changes worked fine for me.
You can try out.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    compileOptions {
          sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
          targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
     }
 }

dependencies {
      compile 'org.apache.opennlp:opennlp:1.6.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created an example repository on how to use OpenNLP in Android, you can refer here: https://github.com/duckyngo/OpenNLP-Android-Example